# Blank screen after "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" with 11.10 live system, alternate installer works but boot fails afer installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, 11.10

When trying to install Ubuntu 11.10, whether I click **Install** or **Try Ubuntu**, I only get a permanent blank screen.

If I use `nomodeset`, it changes to a loading screen, but after about 2 minutes it goes back to the black screen. Before it goes black, I get a few errors -- something like: `bad target number, or passwd error mode`.

I've also tried:

```
xforcevesa, i915.modeset=0, nomodeset, radeon.modeset=0, i915.modeset=1
```

I have tried the alternate installer, which installed fine, however when I boot up, select it from "grub", it goes black.

I did manage to install 10.04, however the screen resolution was 800x600 and I couldn't fix it to 16:9 (my resolution). Also, I would like to use the new 11.10 version.

Comment: please edit your post with your computer specifications, this issue may be some kind of hardware specific.

Answer (score 1):

Newer kernels may have fixed this issue, you should give a shot at [Ubuntu 12.04 beta](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview/Beta1).

Please note that this version is still in development so you might find some bugs and instability until the release.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because the [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) in your computer is not compatible with Ubuntu 10.10 or later.  Ubuntu 10.04 had the driver for it.  So:

Go to BIOS > Security> I / O interface Security> "New card Interface". Set it to Locked.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1662577&page=3

Or use `nolapic` or `acpi = off` to temporarily fix that.